# Ghostscript silent/unattended installation

Tags: ghostscript

I want to install ghostscript silently but actually it does not work. The Winzip SELF-Extractor pops up.

As I read the FAQ on the ghostscript site it should work with parameters /S and /NCRC

From the ghostscript site;

**Can I install Ghostscript on Windows unattended?**

```
Yes, give gsxxxw32/64.exe the /S (for silent) option.
In addition, you can add the /NCRC option (that will suppress
the CRC check, which, unfortunately, pops up a dialogue to show
progress). And /D=<install dir> to change the target directory
for the install.
```

But with my 8.7 Version of Ghostscript it does not work, any ideA?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a recent version of Ghostscript (the current version is 9.15). The version you are using is 5 years old, I believe the documentation you are quoting is for the current version, hardly surprising it doesn't work !

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the recent version doesn’t work either. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62392368/92957) helped me:

```
choco install --yes ghostscript --version=9.24
```

Trying to install without a specific version also failed. Passing 9.24 did the trick.