# Installing Ghostscript in Docker Windows image returned a non-zero code: 1

Tags: windows, docker, nsis, ghostscript

- Dev environment: Windows Server 2019
- Docker version: 19.03.5

The [official Ghostscript documentation](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.20/Install.htm#Install_Windows) says this about installing on Windows:

> #### 4.1 Installing
>
> To install Ghostscript on Windows, you should run the installer executable.
>
> The installer is NSIS-based (see also Release.htm) and supports a few standard NSIS options: /NCRC disables the CRC check, /S runs the installer or uninstaller silently, /D sets the default installation directory (It must be the last parameter used in the command line and must not contain any quotes, even if the path contains spaces. Only absolute paths are supported).

Following this documentation, I put this in my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM jenkins/agent:jdk8-nanoserver-1809

WORKDIR /tmp
ADD https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs952/gs952w64.exe .
RUN C:\tmp\gs952w64.exe /S
```

This is the output of `docker build`:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  5.632kB 
Step 1/4 : FROM jenkins/agent:jdk8-nanoserver-1809 
 ---> 026ce64bdabf
Step 2/4 : WORKDIR /tmp
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fd854f6da0a9
Step 3/4 : ADD https://github.com/ArtifexSoftware/ghostpdl-downloads/releases/download/gs952/gs952w64.exe .
Downloading [==================================================>]  27.64MB/27.64MB 
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 259453368869 
Step 4/4 : RUN C:\tmp\gs952w64.exe /S 
 ---> Running in c86c8393a4fa 
The command 'pwsh.exe -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; C:\tmp\gs952w64.exe /S' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Which means that Ghostscript wasn't installed.

Is this because I didn't specify an installation directory? I'm OK with the default directory.

Or should I forgo manual installation altogether and use some kind of package manager? I don't know how Windows does it nowadays, last time I used Windows we still had to install Trumpet Winsock to get online...

Comment: Without seeing any feedback from the installer its awfully hard to tell; my suspicion would be that the 'user' executing the installer doesn't have permission to create the required directories or something similar, but I know nothing about docker or Jenkins. You can of course simply put the Ghostscript executable and DLL in a convenient folder, but that won't create the Registry keys which some applications depend on.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it!

I made 2 changes:

1. Change base image from `jenkins/agent:jdk8-nanoserver-1809` to `jenkins/agent:jdk8-windowsservercore-1809` (next step won't work if you don't do this, Chocolatey is not suported on Windows Nano Server)
2. Install Chocolatey as package manager

```
FROM jenkins/agent:jdk8-windowsservercore-1809

ADD https://chocolatey.org/installchocolatey.cmd .
RUN .\installchocolatey.cmd
RUN choco install --yes ghostscript --version=9.24 ;\
    choco install --yes imagemagick --version=7.0.10.14 ;\
```

Yes, two separate `RUN` commands. You **must** do this, because the Windows shell needs to be restarted to be able to find Chocolatey. I found this out the hard way, but the Chocolatey installer also says it at the end.